# How does math.perlinnoise work in unity? I know how to use it but i don't know it's formula, etc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to unity and I am currently following a tutorial that uses math.perlinnoise to generate some terrain, but the tutorial doesn't explain how it works so I decided to research it online. I know how to use it but i don't know how it works. All i know is that if i insert 2 decimals that aren't whole numbers, it will return a float. I tried searching some explanations online but all of them were in languages that I'm not familiar(c# is the only language that i understand) and also did not use unity's version of mathf.perlinnoise(i don't know whether or not they're different, though). So could anyone provide any sources that are in C# or give some sources that i can study? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a bit of code and a link to the documentation so that people see that you read it and others can go there can see it. Will help with general understanding

Answer (score 0):

Perlin Noise is essentially a grid of gradients from a minimum value to a maximum value, each rotated at a random angle. The gradients at each point are smoothed based on the surrounding points, creating a smooth wavy grid.

Unity's Mathf.PerlinNoise specifically ranges from 0.0 to 1.0, but often the algorithm is implemented ranging from -1.0 to 1.0.

A visual example of the process is available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise#Algorithm_detail). In those images, the dark purple represents the value -1, and the dark green is the value 1.

You can imagine the low numbers (purple) being valleys, and the high numbers (green) being hills. You can also add more layers of perlin noise at different scales to add more detail and reduce the smoothness.

A great tutorial on algorithms behind various kinds of noise, using C# and Unity, is available by [Catlike Coding](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/noise/).